# Using a for loop to generate a string of numbers out of a range

Tags: python

I need to generate a string of the numbers from 1 to 50 with a for-loop.

my suggestion:

```py
solution = range(1,50)
for i in solution
    print(i++, end ="")
```

it shows me invalid syntax and I don't really get behind the reason. The output should be a string with the number from 1 to 50 added like this (12345....).

How do I do that?

Comment: You are missing a colon at the end of the `for` line. Also, remove the `++`.

Comment: still invalid syntax...

Comment: what version of python is this? 2? because 2 doesn't support `print` this way

Answer (score 1):

1. `variable++` is not Python syntax at all. You might know it from C, C++, Java, JavaScript, or any of the dozens of languages that use it.
2. You're missing a colon after the for loop line.

The Python interpreter should have pointed out at least the latter to you. The former is easily found by Googling.

The following should give the output you need, but know that there are easier ways to do this in Python.

```py
solution = range(1,50)
string_variable = ""  # the i from below will be of type integer, not string.
for i in solution:
    string_variable += str(i)  # += performs appending (or addition depending on the data type), but you'll need to convert i to a string
print(string_variable)
```

---

### Explanation (method 1)

#### Breaking down the problem

Let's think about what you want.

1. You want to consider numbers from 1 to 50.
2. You then want to think about them one at a time.
3. While doing step 2, you want to maintain a "joined" record somewhere, and "join" each number at the end of the record as you consider it.
4. Finally, you want to output that "joined" record.

#### Converting ideas to code

Let's go through each step one at a time, this time in code.

1. Consider numbers from 1 to 50.

   You got this! You saved a `range()` [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) to a variable with 1 and 50 as its endpoints.

   ```py
   solution = range(1, 50)
   ```
2. Think about them one at a time.

   You got this too! By using a `for` loop to iterate over your generator, you are doing this.

   ```py
   for i in solution:
   ```
3. Join the numbers

   This step gotcha :(

   To understand this, you need to know about something called [data types](https://realpython.com/python-data-types/).

   The `range()` generator gives you integer values. Think of this as a proper value: a number that you can manipulate (add, subtract, multiply etc).

   However, when you want to join stuff together (called [concatenating](https://realpython.com/python-string-split-concatenate-join/)), you need to use strings.

   To you and me, a number on a piece of paper is same as the number on a calculator. To a computer, it's not. If it's a string, it's treated equivalently to an alphabet: you cannot do math with it, you can only do stuff like displaying it.

   To concatenate, you must convert to a string. That's why I start with a blank string variable.

   ```py
   string_variable = ""
   ```

   We do this with the following syntax:

   ```py
   str(i)
   ```

   The `str` stands for string.

   The joining part happens with the `+=` operator:

   ```py
       string_variable += str(i)
   ```
4. Output the string

   I think you know how to do this. Just print it out:

   ```py
   print(string_variable)
   ```

Putting it all together:

```py
solution = range(1,50)
string_variable = ""
for i in solution:
    string_variable += str(i)
print(string_variable)
```

---

### Explanation (method 2)

I think your logic was right.

```py
solution = range(1,50)
for i in solution
print(i++, end ="")
```

1. We're removing the `++` because it isn't valid Python syntax. This is the increment operator from languages like C++. In practice, if you were using something like a while loop, you would use this to increase the value of `i` by 1 in each pass of the loop. However, for loops sort of have this idea built into them, so we don't need it.
2. Addition of `:` and indentation by 4 spaces are done because that's way we communicate to Python that the line `print(i, end ="")` is to be executed inside the loop `for i in solution`.

Corrected code:

```py
solution = range(1,50)
for i in solution:
    print(i, end ="")
```

Comment: it still says the syntax is invalid, even though I revomed the ++ and added the colon

Comment: Did you save the code before trying it again?

Comment: @OzymandiazBelzoni I've edited my answer since originally posting. Please refresh your webpage and see if the current version works for you.

Comment: Let me try eccentric

Comment: Alright it worked, but since I am a complete beginner (as you may have guessed) the code feels absolutelty not intuitive to me

Comment: @OzymandiazBelzoni Also note that indentation is important to Python.

Comment: @OzymandiazBelzoni No problem. I'll edit a verbose explanation into my answer—let me know if it works (could take a few minutes).

Comment: Thank you very much! It was honestly the first task we needed to perform...but I don't quite get the part, where you add all the numbers up, so that it forms a string...the code wouldn't have occured to me

Comment: @OzymandiazBelzoni Done. I'll be honest with you, I think I kind of did the wrong thing by introducing string variables and concatenation here, and you initial logic was correct. Sorry. So I'll both explain my code (method 1), and explain the simple changes we need to make to your code to get to work (method 2).

Comment: @eccentricOrange not sure it really matters... but you can also do: `print(*range(1, 50), sep='')`

Comment: @JonClements Yeah, I would have done that too, in my own projects. However, OP stated that they are a beginner (so they know a limited number of—let's say 5—concepts). So, if I introduce three more, that's a lot of information to take in... That's why I bothered to apologise for introducing two more lines. Of course, I'm aware that there are usually tons of solutions in coding, and which one you take is up to some combination of the programmer and the situation. Thanks though :)